# Use DB other than SQL Server with .NET FB app?

Tags: .net, database

Have people had good experiences with solutions other than SQL Server? My host is pretty expensive for adding on SQL Server storage so I'm curious about people's success with other means, especially with scalability in mind.

Thanks...

-Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your host is going to charge a hefty cost to adding SqlServer, the expense is most likely for licensing, setup, maintenance, etc. You may have better luck (read, *a lesser fee*) for setup and monthly maintenance with MySql.

Depending on your data, you also have the option of uploading Open Office Calc files to your host and using MySql data connector. Maybe not very scalable, but if your web app is just starting up, and you don't have the means to pay for the scalability of SqlServer, MySql offers some viable options.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe time for a different host?  Most shared hosting providers I've worked with have pretty inexpensive shared SQL Server hosting offerings, on the order of $10/month or less.  They also seem to throw in a few SQL Server db's with some of their shared hosting plans.  I just checked one of my current hosting providers and they offer add-ons for $1.50/month for one database.  So it doesn't have to be expensive.

SQL Azure is only $10/month for a 1 GB database if you want high availability.

And what about SQL Server Compact Edition?  It's free and not just for desktop and mobile apps any more.  Check out this blog post:  http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/07/getting-started-with-sql-server-compact.html

Comment: +1 for *Maybe time for a different host?* Having different hosting options to negotiate with never hurts.